# Apache POI error loading XSSFWorkbook class

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I'm trying to write a program that works with Excel docs, but the HSSF format is too small for my requirements. I'm attempting to move to XSSF, but I keep getting errors when trying to use it.

I managed to solve the first two by adding xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar and dom4j-1.6.jar to my program, but now this error is coming up, which doesn't seem to be resolved by adding the Apache commons jar available on the Apache website.

The error is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
    at hot.memes.ExcelCreator.main(ExcelCreator.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 52):

Add commons-collections4-x.x.jar file in your build path and try it again.
It will work.

You can download it from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.0

Comment: All Apache POI dependencies are also included in the binary download package!

Comment: See Anshu Kumar's answer below. The 4.0 version is not enough you need Apache Collections 4.1 version to solve this problem. I have checked.

Comment: Namaskar mitro, commons-collections4-x.x.jar does not have ExtendedProperties.java, while commons-collections3-x.x.jar does not have LinkValuedMap.java. How did you overcome that?

Answer (score 31):

commons-collections4-x.x.jar  definitely solve this problem but Apache has removed the Interface ListValuedMap from commons-Collections4-4.0.jar so use updated version 4.1 it has the required classes and Interfaces.

Refer here if you want to read Excel (2003 or 2007+) using java code.

http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-read-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi

Comment: Totally correct, have to download this version.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.1

Comment: This helped me also many thx for it. I just have upgraded to POI 3.15 from 3.14 and identified that my XLSX exports are broken because of this. So I have changed the version from 4.0 to 4.1 and everything works well again.

Answer (score 18):

Hurrah! Adding commons-collections jar files to my project resolved this problem. Two thumbs up to Lucky Sharma.

Solution: Add commons-collections4-4.1.jar file in your build path and try it again. It will work.

You can download it from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.1

Answer (score 13):

Please note that 4.0 is not sufficient since ListValuedMap, was introduced in version 4.1.

You need to use [this maven repository link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.1) for version 4.1.
Replicated below for convenience

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
   <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was using VSCode and adding this to pom.xml helped :)

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, resolved the exception by adding commons-collections4-4.1 jar file to the CLASSPATH user varible of system.
Downloaded from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.1

Answer (score 1):

XSSFWorkbook class is only available in poi-ooxml dependency.
Please check if you are using poi or poi-ooxml.

implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.0.0' -> HSSFWorkbook

implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.0.0' -> XSSFWorkbook

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded pio-3.17
On eclipse: right click on the project folder -> build path -> configure build path -> libraries -> add external jars -> add all the commons jar file from the "lib". It's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add jars in your project class classpath -

1. poi-3.17.jar
2. poi-excelant-3.17.jar
3. poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
4. common-collections-4.4.jar
5. xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
6. poi-ooxml-scehmas-3.17.jar
7. common-compress.jar

There is the following example of your code.

```
package com.sks.xssbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

/**
 * @author ssuman
 *
 */
public class XssBook1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet shhet = workBook.createSheet("sheet1");
        File f1 = new File("sks.xlsx");
        FileOutputStream fileOop = new FileOutputStream(f1);
        workBook.write(fileOop);
        workBook.close();
        System.out.println("File created !!!!!");
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Error ---- "+ex);
        }

    }

}
```