# error when reading an excel file java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, hssfworkbook

I am new to POI. I am trying to read an xlsx file with the code below in Eclipse:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class excel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String excelFilePath = "Books.xlsx";
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

    }
}
```

but when i run it i get this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
    at excel.main(excel.java:19)

What can I do to stop this error?

Comment: take a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670382/apache-poi-error-loading-xssfworkbook-class

Comment: And please what version of java and POI do you use?