# ListValuedMap NoClassDefFoundError when Reading Excel using Apache Poi?

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

While Executing the Program, Below are the issues Compiler is throwing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
at ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

Please help me know how to solve this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache POI error loading XSSFWorkbook class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670382/apache-poi-error-loading-xssfworkbook-class)

Answer (score 2):

you should be good if you add the below jar.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.1

Comment: please remove any older version of jars from your buildpath, an hope you have double checked the version..it is 4.1..

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some required class maybe check your version on pom.xml if you are using eclipse you can do cnt shift T and see if you can open the missing class (ListValuedMap)file and see if it comes from the same jar as you specified in your pom.

Comment: Thanks For responding I am not using POM instead of that I have directly included jar files related to program in the build path