# Apache POI runtime error while creating .xlsx file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I have tried to write a simple code with Java FX to create an .xlsx file:

```
package apachepoi;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ApachePOI_ViewController implements Initializable {
    private void CreateWorkBook() {
        try {
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("NewWorkBook.xlsx"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("NewWorkBook.xlsx written successfully.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            CreateWorkBook();
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

[image]

I have googled this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap
```

and got these two StackOverflow threads:

[Apache POI error loading XSSFWorkbook class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670382/apache-poi-error-loading-xssfworkbook-class)

[ListValuedMap NoClassDefFoundError when Reading Excel using Apache Poi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45657641/listvaluedmap-noclassdeffounderror-when-reading-excel-using-apache-poi/45658781)

I have read these from character to character, but importing `commons-collections4-4.1.jar` file (actually I use 4.4 right now) **didn't solve** the Exception error.

My imported .jar files:

- poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar
- commons-collections4-4.4.jar
- xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar

What else should I do?

Comment: How are you "importing" those JARs?

Comment: In Netbeans right click on the Libraries in the project, and "Add Jar/Folder..." https://i.imgur.com/seOGDwC.png

Comment: You can get rid of many such issues by using maven.

Comment: How are you ensuring that all your dependencies are present at *runtime* and not just at *compile time*?