# Bulk user import failing on wso2 identity server 5.11.0 with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap

Tags: wso2-identity-server

WSO2 Identity Server : 5.11.0
I am facing below error in logs while **importing users using bulk import.**

```
{org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} - org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.bulkimport.ExcelUserBulkImport.createWorkbook(ExcelUserBulkImport.java:135)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.bulkimport.ExcelUserBulkImport.addUserList(ExcelUserBulkImport.java:59)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserRealmProxy.bulkImportUsers(UserRealmProxy.java:2208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserAdmin.bulkImportUsers(UserAdmin.java:563)
        ... 80 more
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap cannot be found by poi_3.17.0.wso2v1**
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 84 more
```

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out user bulk import with WSO2 - Identity Server version 5.11.0 with H2 and I could not reproduce any errors as such. But according to what I see there could be a missing dependency refer [stackoverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40089521/11383375). You can download that missing jar file, add it to `<IS_HOME>/repository/components/lib` folder and try the scenario again after server restart. Furthermore you can validate any other issues regarding this scenario through the [docs](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-users/#creating-a-file-with-users).